# git - move branch "tag" to other commit?

Tags: git

Since a branch is more or less only a tag, that moves automatically to the new commit, I wonder if I can modify this "tag".

Example:

```
             master  
A -- B -- C -- D
```

`git checkout master` would be the same as `git checkout D`

Can I change master to point to commit B?

```
   master
A -- B -- C -- D
```

`git checkout master` would now be the same as `git checkout B`

**Use Case**

Imagine someone has pushed one single commit to the online repository. When I do `git fetch`, I get this commit local, but my master branch still points to the commit before, while origin/master points to the new commit. I just want to move the local master branch to the same commit as origin/master points to.

So, I wouldn't have to merge.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In your push scenario, you would simply merge `origin/master`. Since you don't have any local commits, it will be resolved as a farst-forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 12):

To move the branch Tag to commit B you can do the following:

```
git branch -f master B
```

Using `git branch` instead of `git reset --hard` even preserves your working directory.

Comment: Looks like this would be right, but you reset it to where it already is using this command.  I assume you're going for: git branch -f master B.

Comment: Does this preserve the branches tracking status?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd guess no.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git branch -d master
git branch master
```

It's more logical to me

Comment: Note that you will be in _detached head_ state after your sequence of commands.

Answer (score 0):

An annotation to knittis solution:

After calling to recreate the branchname(master) to point to the commit

```
git branch -f branchname D
```

Don't forget to synchronize HEAD and branchname(master) via:

```
git checkout branchname
```